# I'm very skeptical about installing Ubuntu over my existing Windows 7 OS. As a first time user I have no experience with any Linux Software

Tags: installation

Okay, so I am very nervous about wanting to install Ubuntu onto my PC, I don't want to potentially delete my current Windows 7 OS, and as a first time user I have no experience whatsoever with Linux.

I Urge the Ubuntu Community to assist me in this matter as I do not want to make any mistakes that may potentially jeopardize my system.

I have a 64-bit version of windows 7 if that helps with the answer to this question.

Thank you.

Comment: You should at a minimum boot the live ubuntu desktop and ensure your hardware is working. Most people either dual boot or learn Ubuntu in a virtual machine, ie wubi, dual boot, or VirtualBox.

Comment: So ...before you do anything you make a backup and have no worries?

Comment: Yes, backup. And before installing Ubuntu as dual boot make sure you defragmented thoroughly your hard disk.

Answer (score 1):

You could always install it into your existing windows partition using WUBI, or you could install it into a VirtualBox, that way, you are still running your comfortable windows environment, but can just click over to Ubuntu at will.

Answer (score 0):

No need to install just use a Live USB image :) And when you are ready to install you can also dual boot.

Here is a link for you to follow on how to create a usb stick: 
http://www.ubuntu.com/download/help/create-a-usb-stick-on-windows